# Given $f(x)=\big(\frac{1}{x}\big)^{1/3}$. Is the area bounded by the function and the $x$ axis finite?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Consider the function $f(x)=\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)^{1/3}$ with $x\in[-1,1]$.

I want to find out wether the area bounded by the function and $x$ axis is finite?

Using simple strategy (i.e integrating $f(x)$ from $-1$ to $0$ and then from $0$ to $1$ and taking the absolute values) results in a finite area.

But the doubt is: Since the function $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $0$, the function doesn't even exist at $0$. So how can the area be finite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as $x \in [-1, 0) \cup (0,1]$ you calculate

$$\lim_{t \to 0^{+}}\int_{t}^{1} \frac{1}{x^{1/3}} dx = \lim_{t \to 0^{+}} \frac{3x^{2/3}}{2}\Bigg|_t^1 = \frac{3}{2} - \frac{3}{2}\lim_{t \to 0^{+}} x^{2/3} = \color{#05f}{\frac{3}{2}}$$

Similar approach to $t \to 0^{-}$.